# Trapez Method in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, math, integral

I found a formula in the Internet for calculating the trapezoid method , it works as it should, but I do not see why should I performed the following lines in the **trapez method**:

```
sum = 0.5 * bef + (h * sum);

i= i+ 2
```

The **first iteration** performed by the following command in main :

```
tra[0] = 0.5 * ((b - a) / n) * (function(a) + function(b));
//calculates the first step value
```

the **trapez method** for the next iterations:

```
/**
 * calculate the next step with trapez method
 * @param a -lower limit
 * @param b -upper limit
 * @param bef -previous step value
 * @param n -number of dividing points
 * @return integral area
 */
public static double trapz(double a, double b,double bef, int n)
{
    double sum = 0;
    double h = ((b - a)/n);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 2) {
        sum += function(a + (i) * h);
    }
    sum = 0.5 * bef + (h * sum);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: What formula you found and it is for what ? what algorithm is this ?

Comment: The trapezoidal rule (also known as the trapezoid rule or trapezium rule) is a technique for approximating a definite integral.
The trapezoidal rule works by approximating the region under the graph of the function f(x) as a trapezoid and calculating its area.

Comment: This appears to be drawn from an iterative algorithm that *repeatedly* applies the trapezoid rule to improve its estimate of the integral.  The reason for the line you asked about is surely bound up with the nature of the controlling iteration, which you do not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function would be used in conjunction with a driver loop that doubles the number of subintervals at each iteration, refining the estimated integral until the difference from one iteration to the next is less than some threshold criterion.  It is desirable in such an endeavor to avoid repeating computations that have already been performed, and that's the point of the lines you asked about.

Consider the function values that are needed when applying the trapezoid rule on a given number of subintervals.  Now consider the function values needed for splitting each subinterval in half and applying the trapezoid rule to those subintervals.  Half (give or take 1) of the function values needed in the latter case are the same ones needed in the former.  The code presented simply reuses the previously computed values (`0.5 * bef`), adding to them only the new values (`i = i + 2`).  It must scale down the previous estimate by a factor of two to account for splitting the subintervals in two.

Note that for the code to be right, it appears that argument `n` must represent the number of subintervals of the integration region, *not* the number of dividing points as its documentation claims.